# Django filter database with array and OR operator

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to filter database with Q objects. Here is my code:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

filter_obj = Q(key_value__in=arr)
print(filter_obj)   # (AND: ('key_value__in', [u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5']))
```

As you see it's an `AND` operator. I want to filter with `OR` operator within this array. How can I implement this?

Note: We don't know the items in array.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. You want the items which are in BOTH lists or any one of the lists?

Comment: It's like if (key_value == 1) OR (key_value == 2) OR (key_value == 3)

Comment: Since you use `__in` it means that from the moment *one* of the items matches it is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But then why does it print AND?

Comment: @sundowatch: because if you make complex queries, the tree will consist out of nodes that each have an operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As you see it's an `AND` operator. I want to filter with OR operator within this array. How can I implement this?

The `AND` is simply the default connector if want to *add* extra `Q` objects. But the [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) will succeed from the moment that the `key_value` field has one of the items in the list as value.

We can construct this with an `OR`, we can set the `_connector` parameter, and this then produces:

```
>>> arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> Q(key_value__in=arr, _connector=Q.OR)
<Q: (OR: ('key_value__in', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))>
```

but the two are *equivalent*, both have only one condition, so the `_connector` does not matter.

Using a connector can be useful however. If we have for example:

```
# both conditions should be satisfied
Q(Q(foo=1), Q(bar=2), _connector=Q.AND)
```

whereas if one of the conditions is sufficient, we can work with:

```
# both conditions should be satisfied
Q(Q(foo=1), Q(bar=2), _connector=Q.OR)
```